# how to make proper sidebar height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my sidebar look like this picture:
http://s21.postimg.org/aerg28ih3/image.jpg

When the page height is too small, it looks like this:
https://s21.postimg.org/7ly8i7i4n/big.jpg

When it's too long, it looks like this:
https://s21.postimg.org/qsbfldymf/small.jpg

I had to put fixed values in each page, but I don't want to put fixed values.

```css
body {
  background-color: #edf1f2;
  color: #777;
  font: normal 15px"Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 1040px;
}
header {
  height: 120px;
  background: #171a21;
  background-image: url(images/header.png);
}
header h1 {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
header nav {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 7px;
}
header nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
header nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 20px
}
#side {
  float: left;
  padding: 2%;
  background: #1e262c;
  margin-bottom: -5000px;
  padding-bottom: 60.5%;
}
#side ul li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>WEB</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#.html">1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#.html">2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#.html">3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#.html">4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#.html">5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<div id="side">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h6>Links</h6>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to update question with your HTML as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of CSS's `vh` and `calc` by doing something like this:

```
body, html {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#header {
  height: 100px;
}
#footer {
  height: 100px;
}
#sidebar {
  height: calc(100vh - 200px); /*WINDOW HEIGHT - HEADER & FOOTER */
}
```

What this says is "100% of the window height, minus 200px for the header and footer". The sidebar would then adjust height to always fill the area between the two.

When used effectively, you can do something like [this quick demonstration I whipped up](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/zcryg69j/). Notice that the sidebar will always adapt to fit between the two, regardless of the amount of content.

Comment: but there is no footer in the code, just the header?

Comment: @Johannes All three of his image examples included a footer, stating that the sidebar either didn't reach it, or overlapped it. My example can be used just as easily without a footer by changing it to `calc(100vh - 100px)`, so that it takes up the entire height, minus the 100px header.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my late reply I had exams :)
anyway when I edited my page with your code the whole page become a mess, so I started new page with your code as a base, I used the code from here [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp)
for the header and sidebar, but I have problem that the sidebar moves when I scroll down and I have another problem that the right content doesn't fully show the which is in this case a video, I tried to fix them for hours without success, Here is 



[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9rda0j0/)

Comment: okay so I just add overflow: auto; in the #middle and it fixed the two problem, but now only the right is scrollable and everything else is fixed, here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9rda0j0/1/) I think it doesn't look good and It's better if the whole page is scrollable, so I still need to know how to fix the same both problem

Answer (score 0):

Add `html { height: 100%; margin: 0; }`  and use this CSS for your sidebar:

```
#side {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  padding: 2%;
  background: #1e262c;
  height: calc(100% - 120px);
}
```

It gives it the full height minus the height of the header (120px).

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
    }
body {
  background-color: #edf1f2;
  color: #777;
  font: normal 15px"Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 1040px;
}
header {
  height: 120px;
  background: #171a21;
  background-image: url(images/header.png);
}
header h1 {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
header nav {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 7px;
}
header nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
header nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 20px
}
#side {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  padding: 2%;
  background: #1e262c;
  height: calc(100% - 120px);
}
#side ul li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>WEB</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#.html">1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#.html">2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#.html">3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#.html">4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#.html">5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<div id="side">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h6>Links</h6>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```